# Initializing external lib struct with own struct (decoded JSON) gives type error

Tags: go, struct

I have a struct, which is decoded from a JSON http POST req.
My purpose of having this struct is:
- Simplifying JSON request from client
- Using the structs property data in another (external library) struct.

If i had to only use the external library struct, the client JSON setup will look confusing.
How do i use my structs values inside another struct (and especially their arrays)?

I have a working solution for some of the values with simple types.

Consider the following:
Ext lib struct:

```
type ExtStruct struct {
    From             *Email             
    Subject          string             
    Personalizations []*Personalization
 }
```

My lib struct:

```
type MyStruct struct {
         From            *Email             
         Subject          string             
         Personalizations []*Personalization
     }
```

This is my code as is:

```
myStruct := &MyStruct{}
err := json.NewDecoder(body).Decode(myStruct)
extStruct := &ExtStruct{
    Subject: myStruct.Subject,
    From:    (*extStruct.Email)(myStruct.From),
    Personalizations: []*extStruct.Personalization{
        To: ([]*extStruct.Email)(myStruct.To),
    }}
```

The `Subject`and `From` value works, but i'm getting errors when trying to referencing array values.
I fail to see where i am wrong. AFAIK there's no other option to "simplify" input JSON from a client, only to reference the values in another bigger struct.
I can include the other referenced structs if needed, but think of it as:

```
type A struct {
    RefB []*B
}

type B struct {
    RefC []*C
    Value string
}
type C struct {
    Value string
}
```

And i need my struct to refer to C.

Comment: `ExtStruct` and `MyStruct` are identical, so the client JSON setup will also be identical. How will that make anything less confusing?

Comment: You are right, this is what eventually confused me.
The point was to create less confusing JSON from the client, and then use that data in an external lib., that required more a more complex setup.

Comment: But the JSON will be identical, so all this seems to do is make more work & complexity.

Comment: Not if you see my answer below. The simple built JSON input is being decoded as MyStruct, and the the values used in ExtStruct. As i've said, i don't know if there's a better solution, but that worked for me.

Comment: Are you under the impression that the client JSON is constrained by `ExtStruct` in any way? It is not. The JSON could be `{"Subject": "Hello"}` and `ExtStruct` could be huge, it would not matter; all other non-marshalled fields will be set to their _empty_ values—but the marshall would succeed.

Comment: @JonasG.Drange No mate, the JSON *structure* is constrained by `ExtStruct`. It's the structure of the JSON i am unhappy with from the client perspective.

Comment: "the JSON structure is constrained by `ExtStruct`" doesn't quite make sense to me. There is a _mapping_ between the client JSON and `ExtStruct` and it can be what ever you want—there is no reason for a `MyStruct` intermediary. See for example https://play.golang.org/p/ma-3qcENokh which uses the idiomatic way of creating a mapping. There are many other ways to map.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood, but I would think the ExtStruct initialization would look more like

```
extStruct := &ExtStruct{
    From:             myStruct.From,
    Personalizations: myStruct.Personalizations,
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lqFFBa7SKGg

If they are incompatibly types, `Email` and `Personalization`, you should marshall into `ExtStruct` directly, or do marshalling between types yourself.

I think you should clarify your answer, maybe provide a working (but faulty) example.

Comment: I will add some clarification asap. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found out, it's quite impossible to cast slices.
If you refer to my post:

```
extStruct := &ExtStruct{
    Subject: myStruct.Subject,
    From:    (*extStruct.Email)(myStruct.From),
    Personalizations: []*extStruct.Personalization{
        To: ([]*extStruct.Email)(myStruct.To),
    }}
```

The `Personalizations` slice became:

```
Personalizations: ([]*extStruct.Personalization{{
    To: castStruct(myStruct.To),
}}),
```

And

```
func castStruct(input []*myStruct.Email) []*extStruct.Email {
    output := make([]*extStruct.Email, len(input))
    for index, content := range input {
        output[index] = (*extStruct.Email)(content)
    }
    return output
}
```

I don't know if there's a more clever way to do this, but this is how i succeeded eventually. Just comment this, if you want an elaboration, and I shall try to provide.